# ROS Core build on arch Linux

Tags: ros, boost, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I get the following error when i build the ROS core on a arch linux x86_64 system. I do not know much but a bit of googling pointed me to believe that this could be a boost lib problem that should have been solved in version 1.50 of boost which i have installed but no luck. If someone could help me solve this would be helpful.

Thanks

The Error is below:

```
Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/recorder.cpp.o
/home/zion/ros-underlay/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp: In member function 'void rosbag::Recorder::doRecord()':
/home/zion/ros-underlay/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp:439:42: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
make[2]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/recorder.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45689/ros-core-build-on-arch-linux/) by [vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3350/vijay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lukas Bulwahn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3627/lukas-bulwahn/) on 2012-12-05**:
I encountered the same problem when installing ROS from the sources with rosinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is interesting. So the corresponding line in the cpp file is:

```
#if BOOST_VERSION >= 105000
```

I wonder what BOOST_VERSION expands to. I would actually just manually patch the c++ file locally. Just get rid of the #if, #else and #endif lines and keep the code in the if block in case your boost version is greater or equal than 1.50.

That's sort of an ugly hack but I guess the quickest way to get ROS compiled.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3350/vijay/) on 2012-10-13**:
Hi Lorenz, Could not find the # if BOOST_VERSION anywhere in the source :( i tried grep -rl '#if BOOST' .

**Comment by [vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3350/vijay/) on 2012-10-16**:
Hi All, Could anyone help me for the entries that Lorenz is talking about ? Thanks

**Comment by [Lukas Bulwahn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3627/lukas-bulwahn/) on 2012-12-05**:
I did not understand the answer either before looking at https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/10